# Why I am not seeing the editor's name on my post?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

I got notification for an edit to one of my answers on Stack Overflow. When I clicked to see the suggested edit then I found this:

[image: screenshot of edits]

The bottom right corner says *"proposed 1 min ago by an anonymous user"*.  Why? Who is this anonymous user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An anonymous user suggested the edit.  There's no name to show you besides that.

It's possible for anonymous users to suggest edits.  They should be treated like any other person suggesting an edit to content on the site; if it's good then it should be accepted; if it's poor then it should be rejected.